# Prepeared SQL Statement PHP - PDO to update Postgres Column of type hstore

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, hstore

I am trying to update data in the column "name_local". This column is of type "hstore". The key would be for example 'fr' and the value 'Allemagne'.

If I execute the whole thing manually in the SQL console it works.

However, when I try to execute it as a prepared statement (PHP PDO), I always get syntax errors.

I think it is because of the quotation marks. I have also tried different ways. Single and double quotes, I escaped them. None of them worked.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This works fine in the console:

```
UPDATE country SET name_local = name_local || '''fr'' => ''Allemagne'''::hstore WHERE id = 1234;
```

This works also in PHP:

```
$stmt = $dbh2->prepare("UPDATE country SET name_local = name_local || '''fr'' => ''Afghanistan'''::hstore WHERE id = 996;");
    $stmt->execute();
```

But if i do this:

```
$stmt = $dbh2->prepare("UPDATE country SET name_local = name_local || ''':iso2'' => '':name'''::hstore WHERE id = 996;");
    $stmt->execute(['iso2'=>'en', 'name' => 'Afghanistan']);
```

i get this :

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :iso2

Comment: Does matching the named parameters exactly work? ie: `[':iso2'=>'en', ':name' => 'Afghanistan']`

Comment: I would bind the entire `'''fr'' => ''Allemagne'''` mess as a single placeholder and see if it works.